# MySQL unique constraint across two columns

Tags: mysql, database-design, constraint

I have a table defining relationships

```
Src smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
Dst smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
other fields
```

I need to add a constraint that says if a given values is present in one of the columns, then.
1) Cannot be duplicated in the same column.
2) Cannot be duplicated in the other column either.

This is invalid

```
src    dst
1      354
666    1
```

Since the value 1 is present in the first row, it cannot be present in the second row.

How can I define this type of constraint?

I'm doing a lightweight check at application lever. But I want the DB to ensure it.

Update: Currently I have 7 different types of relationships, and one table per relationship type.

Update 2: Originally this was only one table containing all the relationships, now I'm exploding it

```
# variante
Create TABLE `productsRelationships3` (
  `relSrc` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `relDst` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY `src-dst-3` (relSrc, relDst),
  UNIQUE  `src-3` (relSrc)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

# this is the import
INSERT INTO productsRelationships3 SELECT relSrc, relDst FROM  productsRelationships WHERE relType=3;
DELETE FROM productsRelationships WHERE relType=3;

#this is the retrieval. The dummy rows are there because I do a UNION
#SELECT relSrc, relDst, 3 as relType, relTypeDesc, 0 as fracQty, 28281 as source FROM productsRelationships3 LEFT JOIN productsRelationshipsDesc on 3=relTypeID WHERE relDst=28281 OR relSrc=28281;



# fraccion
#relType is from the old 1-table schema. It's going to be deleted
Create TABLE `productsRelationships6` (
  `relSrc` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `relType` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 6,
  `fracQty` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `relDst` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY `src-dst-6` (relSrc, relDst),
  UNIQUE  `src-6` (relSrc),
  UNIQUE  `dst-6` (relDst),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_type_desc_6` FOREIGN KEY (`relType`) REFERENCES `productsrelationshipsdesc` (`relTypeID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

#import
INSERT INTO productsRelationships6 SELECT relSrc, relType, fracQty, relDst FROM  productsRelationships WHERE relType=6;
```

The other tables are basically the same as productsRelationships3

Comment: Are these (`relSrc` and `relDst`) foreign keys to some other tables? Please include that info, too. And if yes, are the foreign keys from `productsRelationships3` and from `productsRelationships6` (and `productsRelationshipsX`) all pointing to (referencing) the same tables? Or different ones?

Comment: They should be foreign keys to a products table. They all are referencing to the same products table (products.prodID). A given product can participate in more than one relationship.

Answer (score 5):

I have modified [ypercube's solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29338) a little bit, so that both source and destination are not null, as is guaranteed by the original design. My `CHECK` constraints are commented out, as they apparently will not work in MySQL. I kept them as comments because they document my intent, and they will work on other RDBMS.

```
CREATE TABLE PointType
( PointTypeID tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
  TypeDescription CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (PointTypeID),
  UNIQUE (TypeDescription)
) ;

INSERT INTO PointType 
  (PointTypeID, TypeDescription)
VALUES
  (1, 'Source'), 
  (2, 'Destination') ;

CREATE TABLE PointUsageQuota
( RouteID int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PointTypeID tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
  PointID smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (PointID),     -- and this is what all the fuss is about
  UNIQUE (RouteID , PointID, PointTypeID), -- target for the foreign keys
  FOREIGN KEY (PointTypeID)
    REFERENCES PointType (PointTypeID)
) ;

CREATE TABLE Route
( RouteID int unsigned NOT NULL,
  SourcePointID smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  SourceTypeID tinyint unsigned NOT NULL, 
      -- CHECK(SourceTypeID = 1),
  FOREIGN KEY (RouteID , SourcePointID, SourceTypeID) 
    REFERENCES PointUsageQuota (RouteID , PointID, PointTypeID) ,
  DestinationPointID smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  DestinationTypeID tinyint unsigned NOT NULL, 
      -- CHECK(DestinationTypeID = 2),
  FOREIGN KEY (RouteID , DestinationPointID, DestinationTypeID) 
    REFERENCES PointUsageQuota (RouteID , PointID, PointTypeID) ,
  --  other fields
  PRIMARY KEY (RouteID)
) ;
```

Testing:

```
insert into PointUsageQuota
values(1,1,666),(1,2,354);

INSERT INTO Route VALUES (1, 666, 1, 354, 2);
-- this fails:
INSERT INTO Route VALUES (2, 666, 1, 354, 2);
-- this fails too:
INSERT INTO Route VALUES (2, 354, 1, 666, 2);
```

Comment: This is far better answer than mine. And if the OP wants to allow same source and destination in the same Route, then the `PointType` table and columns are not needed, making the solution much simpler.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible to have this constraint with the current design. If you can change that and assuming the table is now:

```
CREATE TABLE Route
( RouteID int unsigned NOT NULL,
  Src smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  Dst smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  -- other fields
  PRIMARY KEY (RouteID)
) ;
```

you can split into 2 tables and move the two columns into the new table, combining them into one column (`SrcDst`). A small reference table (`PointType`) with just 2 rows will help enforce the requirements that you have a `Src` and a `Dst` and no more:

```
CREATE TABLE Route
( RouteID int unsigned NOT NULL,
  --- other fields
  PRIMARY KEY (RouteID)
) ;

CREATE TABLE PointType
( PointTypeID tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
  TypeDescription CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (PointTypeID),
  UNIQUE (TypeDescription)
) ;

INSERT INTO PointType 
  (PointTypeID, TypeDescription)
VALUES
  (1, 'Source'), 
  (2, 'Destination') ;

CREATE TABLE RoutePoint
( RouteID int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PointTypeID tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
  SrcDst smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (RouteID, PointTypeID),
  UNIQUE (SrcDst),                       -- and this is what all the fuss is about
  FOREIGN KEY (RouteID)
    REFERENCES Route (RouteID)
      ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (PointTypeID)
    REFERENCES PointType (PointTypeID)
) ;
```

This means that any row on the old `Route` table will now be 1 row in the new `Route` and 2 rows in the `RoutePoint` table.

This means that now you can't simply `INSERT` into the `Route` table. You have to use a transaction that ensures that if a row is inserted at `Route` table, 2 rows are also inserted at the `RoutePoint` table. Otherwise you may have rows in `Route` without `Src` or `Dst`.

Similar changes have to be made to the `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements of the two tables, so no row is accidentally changed or deleted from the `RoutePoint` table for example, leaving a row in `Route` without a related `Src` or `Dst` data.

Comment: The original design guarantees that both source and destination are not null. IMO with your design one or both can be missing.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov: That is correct. INSERT procedures have to take care of that. (and DELETE/UPDATE as well). Is there any other way to implement this constraint?

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with a trigger.

[See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63f87/1) for a working model.  Change the 2nd INSERT to a duplicate value and you'll see the insert fail with an error message.  Bailing from a BEFORE INSERT trigger with a fatal SIGNAL prevents the insert from actually happening.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Route_bi BEFORE INSERT ON Route FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
      DECLARE err_msg VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL; 

      IF EXISTS(SELECT x.Dst FROM Route x WHERE x.Dst = NEW.Src) THEN
          SET err_msg = CONCAT_WS('','cannot insert Src value ',NEW.Src,'; already exists as a Dst');
          SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = err_msg;
      END IF;

      IF EXISTS(SELECT x.Src FROM Route x WHERE x.Src = NEW.Dst) THEN
          SET err_msg = CONCAT_WS('','cannot insert Dst value ',NEW.Dst,'; already exists as a Src');
          SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = err_msg;
      END IF;
  END;
```

The Src and Dst columns each need a UNIQUE KEY, which will prevent duplicate values in the same column.

You'll also have to handle the condition in a similar BEFORE UPDATE trigger to avoid changing values to duplicates later.